# Deleting selected feature in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have problems with deleting a selected feature in openlayers 3. Last week I've spend reading this forum and ol API and trying to find an answer to my problem. 
I want to draw some polygons, be able to select them (or at least one) and then delete the selected feature. With my code I can draw polygons and select them but I've not been able to delete them. What goes wrong?
I started playing with openlayers 3 two weeks ago. I hope my problem is not a missing semicolon somewhere...

```
var features = new ol.Collection(); 
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#ffcc33',
                width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#ffcc33'
                })
            })
        })
  }); 
featureOverlay.setMap(map); 
var draw; 
var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
function addInteraction(){
    if ((typeSelect.value) !== 'None') {
        draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            features: features,
            type: (typeSelect.value)
            });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
    }
    else {
        draw.finishDrawing();
    }
}
var select = null;  
var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick
});
var selectElement = document.getElementById('type2');
var selectedFeature =selectSingleClick.getFeatures();
var changeInteraction = function() {
    if (select !== null) {
        map.removeInteraction(select);
        }
    var value = selectElement.value;
    if (value == 'singleclick') {
        select = selectSingleClick;         
        } 
        else {
            select = null;
        }
    if (select !== null) {
        map.addInteraction(select);         
        }
    };
selectElement.onchange = changeInteraction;
changeInteraction();
typeSelect.onchange = function() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    addInteraction();
    };
addInteraction();
function deleteHandler(){featureOverlay.removeFeature(selectedFeature)};
var deleteFeature = function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 46){ 
        deleteHandler()
        }
    };
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
      }
```

Comment: If there some form of error message or feedback? Or just the delete just not do anything?

Comment: Delete just does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove features from the source, not the layer. So do featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(feature); But since you don't get an error message, I wonder if your code gets executed at all. Place breakpoints and debug it if not.

Comment: I found error message "TypeError: featureOverlay.removeFeature is not a function". But I don't understand why it's not a function.

Comment: .EDIT: I changed it as featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(feature); and now I get TypeError: this.s[b] is undefined
...k.Rf=function(a){var b=x(a).toString();this.s[b].forEach(Ea);delete this.s[b];va...

Comment: Edit2: I had removeFeature(features) ---> changed it (feature) an now the error message is ReferenceError: feature is not defined
function deleteHandler(){featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(feature)}; There is also another error message: TypeError: a is null ol.js(line 646 col 4)